# Parentless QWidget detect X clicked and return Widget name

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt6

I wonder if someone could tell me if its possible to have a close event handler linked to a parentless window's x button. In the following simple example I open a QWidget into a new window. However, the closeEvent() handler doesn't work. I am aware if used self.show() the close event would work but I would like to know if its possible to have an close event handler this way?

The other question I have is how would one know which QWidget had the x clicked if I had multiple pop up windows like this. I am aware of sender() and text() to get button names. Is there a similar method to get the variable name linked to the QWidget (example:self.me) when clicked. Thank you

```
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # set text layout
        self.label = QLabel("Test")
        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.label)
        #
        self.me = QWidget()
        self.me.setLayout(self.vbox)
        self.me.show()



    def closeEvent(self, event):
        print("Closed")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: It doesn't work because that `closeEvent` is implemented for the `Window` class, while you want it to handle for the `self.me` widget. The simple solution is to create a subclass of QWidget and implement `closeEvent` for *that*. If you want to "intercept" the close event from another object, then the solution is to use signals (see [this answer](//stackoverflow.com/a/70238274)) or install an event filter. Note that QDialog already provides similar mechanisms by default and it's probably what you want to use.